# Call to undefined method DateTime::getTimezone()

Tags: laravel

For some reason most of my pages are giving this error "Call to undefined method DateTime::getTimezone()". I'm kind of positive that the pages that have this error got a `->created_at->diffForHumans()` function. I still have no idea whats causing this.. It has been working fine since forever.

I tried updating my packages but there was no luck there.. Searched around for the function itself or inside my controllers.. also no luck. Checked my time zone in config/app.php and it had the same time zone that I've always had which is Asia/Amman

Comment: Did you tried using 
Carbon::parse($object->created_at)->diffForHumans()

Comment: No I haven't.. This line of code is called in a lot of places.. I can't go around and fix it like that. It was working fine.. I dont know what happened :S

Comment: I tried doing it now.. No luck either :(

Comment: Did you defined any accessor in eloquent model?

Comment: Nope... Its just so weird... I'm not sure how did this happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept changing the php version and it eventually worked. It was 7.1.22 and I changed it to 7.2.* and it worked just fine...

Answer (score 2):

Check this discussion please: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24886

As it say there:

> This issue is closed as it is not an issue with Laravel; it was an
>   issue with the PHP docs at the time, which have since been updated. I
>   would suggest you review your own code and make sure it's not a
>   namespace problem (i.e. use new \DateTime instead of new DateTime) and
>   if you still can't figure it out, post a question on StackOverflow
>   with the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the error.
>
> Edit:
>
> Since this was after a Composer update, I would guess that the problem
>   lies with one of the packages that were updated. The error message
>   should give you the exact line number producing the error, which
>   should help you determine what package is causing the error. Then file
>   a bug report (or pull request) against that package if possible.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The error happens in in Carbon.php line 577, in this folder exactlyvendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php

Comment: I'm not using New Datetime directly.. I'm using diffForHumans(). And its causing the above error. Still no luck in solving it with this :S

Comment: Try running this three commands one after another:

php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize

Comment: I updated them and reverted back to the normal... but everytime I update I get this warning : Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run ".\vendor\bin\upgrade-carbon" to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize I tried running the command but it wants me to update laravel in order to update carbon. I even tried updating it even though its a bad idea, still had so many dependencies errors.